# Transverse object array and replace the value of all fields in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, named, typed

quick question (and maybe easy) for y'all:

I got this array:

```
this.skins = {
    "hologramDark": {
        dialog: {
            default: "bgDialog"
        },
        button: {
            default: "btnDefault",
            disabled: "btnDisabled",
            focused: "btnFocused",
            pushed: "btnPushed",
        }
    }
};
```

And I need to (coming from C#+LINQ world) do a "for each item in "hologramDark", replace dialog "default:"'s value with the result of a function (for example, `assignImage(dialog.default)`), then for each buttons's values (default, disabled, focused, etc) do the same thing.

Any pointers? I've worked with normal arrays [] but I don't know how to transverse these ones.

Thanks!

Comment: That's not a _JavaScript Array_..

Comment: You're right, my bad. I made this post a bit quick before I started to go back home from work. Though sometimes I use them as arrays, it's more an object than an array, thanks for the correction :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over properties of an *Object* using `for..in`

```
var obj = this.skins.hologramDark, key; // remember to var
for (key in obj) { // loop over each key
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // if the key is on the obj (not inherited)
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') { // and the property is another object
            obj[key].default = 'foo'; // set the property default
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `hasOwnProperty` check is not necessary here and might be confusing.

Comment: It makes sense though, if you're working with an OOP system in JS. Thanks a lot for the help Paul! :D code worked perfectly :)

Comment: @PaulS. Doesn't `null` have type `object`? (See `console.log(typeof null)`)